# Save DOM and state in localstorage (Angular)

Tags: html, angular, session, ngrx

I am currently working on a wizard, where I have to fix a bug on step 5 on this wizard. The application doesn't hold the state in the url, so I have to complete step 1,2,3,4 every time I want to see step 5.

I can not just fix the wizard, so it holds the state (just not a possibility).

I want to save my whole application state (including everything) into some storage. And whenever I refresh the page, I wish to be able to load that previous state, so that EVERYTHING is completely the same.

1. Is this possible?
2. Can it be done with https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngrx-store-localstorage ?

Comment: Voting down without a comment should be illegal.

Comment: Leverage localStorage + query param to maintain the state and current step count

Comment: @Vikas as I wrote - that i not a possibility.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible by using cookies. The only client side way to save your data and retrieve it after refreshing the page/app is the cookies, because all the other state storage you mentioned will be destroyed by every refreshing.

We can imagine an another scenario, that we will use a database in a the server side but I think you are talking only about the client side.

If you can provide more details so we can discus more.

A simple example about using cookies is in this link:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-cookie-service

Comment: I think localStorage might be a better choice than cookies.